# Azure Functions with trigger timer don't show logs under Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm testing my Azure Functions and facing a funny problem. I want to see if a function was running and the result. I'm opening the function and then my function called **getTokenRefresh**. Apparently, this function has never started.

[image]

After a couple of hours, I decided to open Application Insights. Surprise! All logs are there.

[image]

If I run a function from the portal and open again monitor and click on the Logs tab, I don't see any logs. Again I can find everything only in Application Insights.

Another interesting thing is other functions in this Azure Functions, show me all details (believe me is the same function).

[image]

In the code point of view, I'm using dependency injection in all functions like:

```
public class GetTokenRefreshTimer
{
    private ILogger _log;

    public GetTokenRefreshTimer(ILogger<GetTokenRefreshTimer> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    [FunctionName("getTokenRefreshTimer")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */20 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        _log.LogInformation("GetTokenRefresh starts");
    }
}
```

Comment: The situation you are talking about in your question is existing for a long time. The 'logs' in your function is fragile, it is not always show the logs of your function. Basically, whether your function app runs depends on whether the logs in kudu exist. The Application Insights is getting information from the log files in kudu.

Comment: The logs of function on portal is not important. If you want to know whether your function is running you need to see the logs file in kudu.(It is fundamental, not the logs on portal.)

Answer (score 2):

The logs of azure function is fragile. So sometimes you can not see the logs, but this doesn't mean the azure function is not run.

If you want to know the function is running you need to go to the kudu of your azure function and see the logs file of your function app.(The logs in Application Insights is coming from this place.)

The logs file is in the place:

Open your brower and go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, and then click into LogFiles/Application/Functions/Function/yourtriggername . You will find the log file in this place.

Comment: Why is there a section with logs then? It is enough to open Application Insights. The new UI for Azure Functions is not great. The old one is working better